# Why are my locally hosted Google fonts not working?

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts

I want to host my Google Font locally. I downloaded the files from Google Webfonts Helper and uploaded to public_html/fonts. I added the given code to my theme's style.css (see below).

Then I turned on "Disable Google Fonts" in the Clearfy plugin which actually removes the gstatic and googleapis requests on GTmetrix. However, my local fonts don't show.

Purging cache and server cache doesn't help. I checked the URL of the font location in my browser, it downloads the font, so I assume the path is correct.

Any ideas where the problem could be?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-300.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-300.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-300.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-300.svg#Comfortaa') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
/* comfortaa-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-regular.svg#Comfortaa') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
/* comfortaa-700 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-700.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-700.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('https://myurl.com/fonts/comfortaa-v28-latin-700.svg#Comfortaa') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

body{ font-family:"Comfortaa",sans-serif; }
```

Comment: I would try to erase this part: `local(''),`

Comment: I removed them all, same result though. I don't get it

Comment: [Here](https://www.jasom.net/host-google-fonts-locally-in-wordpress-theme/) is my tutorial on how to host Google Fonts locally within WordPress theme, Maybe it will help somebody. NOTE: I download only `woff2` fontset. NOTE2: I'm not posting an answer here since markup of Google Fonts css in question is obsolete now.